# Can't get Jquery to load

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am a beginner in Jquery and I have a problem. I can't get Jquery to load on my page. I don't know if it is my code or file placement.

**My Head of HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- ...Before </body>... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainScript.js"></script> 
</body>
```

**My Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

I hope you can help

Comment: Can't fadeIn the `document` . Always provide a description of what you expect your code to do. Broken code isn't a good substitute for a proper explanation. A quick test would be to put `alert('it works')` inside `document.ready` to make sure your script file is loading. Also learn to use browser dev tools (F12). Any errors will show up in `console`. You can edit question to provide further details at any time

Comment: Hmm. Have you opened the body tag? because the code snippet you posted does not have an open body tag. I can see no other problem with the markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are opening and closing both your `<head>` and your `<body>`.  In order to make sure it's working, it's probably a good idea to put something in your body before adding JavaScript.

Example of a typical, barebones HTML structure with scripts/stylesheets linked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script> /*YOU CAN LOAD THIS IN YOUR BODY OR HEAD, AS LONG AS IT'S BELOW YOUR JQUERY*/

  <h1>Some Title to Make Sure It's Working</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Another thing to be aware of is making sure that your `src` URLs are correct.

For example, let's say my `index.html` is in my main project folder, and my `scripts.js` is in my `js` folder.  I would link to it the way I did above in my example.

One way of checking that you did this correctly is by first putting something like this in your JavaScript file:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     alert('Scripts.js is linked!');
  });
```

If you see an alert when you open your `index.html` file, then both your jQuery and main JS files are linked.

Comment: The Reason that I don't want to put my whole html is that I am afraid that someone will steal my code.

Comment: @JimmyMac I edited my answer - try that `alert` and see if it's linked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that jQuery is not loading.The problem is that the fade in function only works on elements that are hidden.Copy and paste the code below into a new page and you will see that the red block slowly fades into view over a period of 5 seconds and it's working because of `display:none` in the style.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myDiv").fadeIn(5000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="myDiv" style="background-color:red; width:300px; height:300px;display:none;">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to make sure jQuery is loading just place an `alert('loaded');` inside `$(document).ready...`